# Why doesn't my code to print a different message for specific condition work?

Tags: javascript

My homepage prompts you to enter your name upon entry, but I want it to print a special message when i enter my nickname. Instead, it prints the same message every time.

```
window.onload = function namePrompt() {
  let person = prompt("Please enter your name", "");
    if (person != null) {
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML =
    "welcome, " + person + ", to the pyrogaming/covid2009 homepage!";
  }
  else if (person = pyro || Pyro || PYRO) {
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML =
    "hey, me! hope you've been making substantial changes!";
  }
}
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`person = pyro || Pyro || PYRO` is not valid JS

There are three errors. `=` is assignment, not comparison and you would need quotes and test each one with ===

```
person === "pyro" || person ==="Pyro" || person === "PYRO"
```

Instead use toLowerCase and a [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). In any case stay DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)

I also recommend eventListener instead of onload

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const person = prompt("Please enter your name", "");
  if (!person) return; // empty string or null
  const text = person.toLowerCase() === "pyro" ? 
    "hey, me! hope you've been making substantial changes!" : 
    `welcome, ${person}, to the pyrogaming/covid2009 homepage!`;
  document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = text;
})
```

```html
<span id="name"></span>
```

Answer (score -1):

1. You need to first check the name if it's yours and after that display the default message
2. When comparing, use `===`, not `=` - this one is "assign value", not comparing
3. Use string values instead of just `PYRO`
4. I'd also suggest to use `toLowerCase` method, so you don't need to worry about input case. "Pyro", "PYRO", "pyro" - they all will be the same for comparison

```js
window.onload = function namePrompt() {
  let person = prompt("Please enter your name", "");
  if (person != null) {
      if(person.toLowerCase() === 'pyro') {
        document.getElementById("name").innerHTML =
          "hey, me! hope you've been making substantial changes!";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("name").innerHTML =
          "welcome, " + person + ", to the pyrogaming/covid2009 homepage!";
      }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="name"></div>
```

Comment: The `prompt()` has a default `""` so this is not a great test: `if (person != null) {`  I would suggest you use the "falsey" nature of strings and use `if (!!person) {`

Comment: Yes, that's right. I just didn't want to change the parts that weren't directly related to the question.

Answer (score -1):

```js
window.onload = function namePrompt() {
  let person = prompt("Please enter your name", "");
  var msg
  if (person != null) {
    if (person.toLowerCase() == "pyro") {
      msg =
        "hey, me! hope you've been making substantial changes!";
    } else {
      msg = "welcome, " + person + ", to the pyrogaming/covid2009 homepage!";
    }
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = msg
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="name"></div>
```

Comment: Add a little information about what you did and why

Comment: Oh I just fixed the code, staying more or less true to the origin. Thanks for the tip

Comment: Why not use ===, and why not initialise msg to welcome and only change if `person.toLowerCase() === "pyro"` - save an else

Comment: I'm not sure that setting value for variable twice is cheaper than else - performance wise - since there is already usage of `if`.  Also - style wise - it seems symmetrical and nice.

Comment: The `prompt()` has a default `""` so this is not a great test: `if (person != null) {` I would suggest you use the "falsey" nature of strings and use `if (!!person) {`  As an aside I am not a huge fan of omitting semi-colons in JavaScript as it can lead to hard to find bugs.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss !!person does not do it either.

Comment: Well I answered first and didn't edit my answer 5 times. Seems cruel to get a minus votes but It's cool

Comment: Well, pressing `OK` on the prompt will show `welcome, , to the pyrogaming/covid2009 homepage!` - that is not ideal I think. Also as I said, no explanation what was wrong in OP's code. No shame in refining an answer.

Comment: @mplungjan For the case in this code set (null or empty string:the default `if (!!person)` returns `true` if it is not the default. Now, given it will never be `null` given the default, that condition takes care of both those as a simple condition.  There are other cases such as space only strings that may come into play but that is a problem decision not a technical issue per se if it should be trimmed and then check or if ONLY spaces are valid.  Fun stuff.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss apologies. !!person can be used to wrap the code you want to execute. I use !person to leave

Comment: @mplungjan No worries - my explanation was/is for the most part for those new to the concept for that conditional use in JavaScript - FWIW I upvoted your answer as the one I like the best overall but not passing judgement on the others outside of my comments.